# How do I resolve the Firestore/Auth Emulator error [cloud_firestore/permission-denied] false for get at Line 5?

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-authentication

It looks like there is a problem with request.auth when I'm using the Firebase emulators. It seems that it is always null. I am assuming that the get referred to in the error corresponds to the read in the firestore rules.

firestore.rules:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
    }
  }
}
```

web/index.html

```
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.6.1/firebase-app.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.6.1/firebase-auth.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.6.1/firebase-firestore.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.6.1/firebase-functions.js"></script>
```

lib/main.dart

```
Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp(
    options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
  );

  try {
    var firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;

    var auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

    var algoliaKeys = {
      'appid': '...',
      'apikey': '...'
    };

    if (window.location.hostname == 'localhost') {
      // Set up for using Firebase Emulators
      await auth.useAuthEmulator('localhost', 9099);
      FirebaseFirestore.instance.useFirestoreEmulator('localhost', 8080);
      FirebaseFunctions.instance.useFunctionsEmulator('localhost', 5001);
      firestore.settings =
          const Settings(host: 'localhost:8080', sslEnabled: false);

      // Use Alogolia Development Indices
      algoliaKeys['appid'] = '...';
      algoliaKeys['apikey'] = '...';
    }

    var searchClient = Algolia.init(
        applicationId: algoliaKeys['appid'], apiKey: algoliaKeys['apikey']);

    runApp(MyApp(
        repository: Repository(firestore, searchClient),
        authentication: Authentication(auth)));
  } catch (e) {
    print('Error in main: $e');
  }
}
```

When I replace if request.auth != null with if true I am able to read the expected document. So request.auth is coming in as null.

I have updated firebase-tools to 11.25.1.

I have seen issues refer to downgrading the Firebase JavaScript SDK to 8.3.1 or upgrading to 9.9.0. To be honest, I am not sure what this means. I've looked at:
[Add Firebase to your Flutter app](https://firebase.google.com/docs/flutter/setup?platform=web);
[Get Started with Firebase Authentication on Flutter](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/flutter/start);
[Learn more about Web and Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/learn-more#add-sdks-cdn)

I have tried replacing 8.6.1 with 8.3.1, 9.9.0, and 9.18.0 in the CDN links in web/index.html expecting that the issue didn't yet exist or had been fixed in those versions as expressed here: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/3258.

Comment: How do you sign in the user with Firebase Auth?

Comment: @PeterKoltai, email/password.

Comment: Are you logging in as the user between `useAuthEmulator` and calling firestore? It's likely that whatever user login you have is invalid after connecting to the emulator.

Comment: @Chris, I don't believe so. Logging in happens after the emulators are connected. If the user is authenticated, then they able to continue to the rest of the app.